# Django sales campaign model with list of foreign keys that can only appear in one sales campaign?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create a sales campaign which stores a list of books (Items). But the book should only be applied to one sales campaign — ie. it should not be able to appear in two campaigns.

I have the following model:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):

    campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default='Special Offer')
    included_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    fixed_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=2)
```

But I think the included_items field might be of the wrong field type. From reading other questions and the Django manual, I think I may be approaching this back to front. Perhaps I should be tackling this from the Item model instead? (Shown below for reference)

```
class Item(models.Model):

    sku = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, 
        default=create_new_sku)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField('Genre', blank=True)
    author = models.ManyToManyField('Author', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    age_range = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Age_range')
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, default=0)
    set_sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    original_sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=False, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each item can only belong to one campaign you should be using a ForeignKey to campaign in the Item model to create your many-to-one relationship

Comment: thank you - I suspected that might be the case. But how do I store the included items in the sales campaign model?

Comment: you dont, you can retrieve them using campaign.Item_set.all()

Comment: aha! Thank you so much - a much needed and timely answer :)

Comment: Mark the answer as answered if it's correct please:)

Answer (score 2):

Actually your design is fine.

Using a ForeignKey from @Henty's answer on the `Item` model still runs into issues where if a campaign becomes inactive (`active=False`), the `Item` model needs to nullify the ForeignKey to allow other campaigns to offer it. In addition, an `Item` model's data should only have information about that instance. To me I think it's weird having a foreign key to a campaign in an `Item` model since that data is irrelevant to a book. You probably want to read up on [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

That being said, you should manually specify your [many-to-many intermediary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table as you'll need to apply a unique constraint in it so that only one active campaign can offer the book.

This intermediary table will also have fields such as the `discount` or `sale_price` of the book since different campaigns can offer different discounts/prices. I'm assuming `price` in your `Item` model is the base retail price on your book so `discount`, `set_sale_price`, `original_sale_price`, and `final_price` are not needed - again, refer back to data normalization.

In addition, you will need to copy over the `active` field from your `Campaign` instance to your intermediary table because it will be needed for the unique constraint. This is done by overriding the `save` method on your intermediary table to copy over the `active` value from the `Campaign` instance.

You'll also have to override the `save` method on your `Campaign` model to update the `active` field on your intermediary instances when you activate/deactivate a campaign.

```py
class Campaign(models.Model):
    campaign_name = ...
    included_items = models.ManyToManyField(
        Item,
        through='CampaignItem',
        through_fields=('campaign', 'item')
    )
    active = ...
    fixed_price = ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # pre-save, update associated campaign-item instances
        CampaignItem.objects.filter(campaign=self).update(active=self.active)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class CampaignItem(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(editable=False)
    discount = ...
    sale_price = ...
    # add any other relevant fields related to this campaign item

    class Meta:
        # add constraint where item can only be in one active campaign
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['item'],
                condition=Q(active=True),
                name='unique_active_item')
        ]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # copy over the `active` value from campaign
        self.active = self.campaign.active
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```